# Why is the width of the background being squeezed with animation when I only applied the animation to the rocket object?

Tags: object, animation, swiftui, geometryreader

I've used the GeometryReader to give an animation effect on the rocket object,
but the background keeps getting affected by it somehow.
Also I think that's what's causing the rocket to lag while moving.

1. How do I make the rocket go out of the screen in trailing and reappear from leading on a loop?
2. How do I stop the background from being affected by the animation?

Below is the code:

import SwiftUI

struct ActionView: View {

```
@State var animate: Bool = false

let animation: Animation = Animation.linear(duration: 10.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        ZStack {
            Image("galaxy")
                .resizable()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
            VStack {
                HStack(spacing: 180) {
                    Image("rocket")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .offset(y: -150)
                    Image("rocket")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .offset(y: -150)
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: 120, alignment: .leading)
                }
                .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: 120,                           alignment: animate ? .leading : .trailing)
                
                VStack {
                    Image("me")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 200)
                        .offset(x: 35)
                    
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Image("DotButton")
                            .shadow(color: .white, radius: 10, x: 0.0, y: 0.0);                            Spacer()
                        Image("SlashButton")
                            .shadow(color: .white, radius: 10, x: 0.0, y: 0.0);                            Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .onAppear {
                withAnimation(animation) {
                    animate.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}